# Android Studio and power outage

Tags: android, android-studio-3.0

There were two power outages in less than 30 minutes while working with Android Studio 3.0.1. Ever since, the editor shows all Android classes in my project as `Cannot resolve`, all packages as `Unused import`s and, naturally, a thick red blob of errors at the right of every Java class in the project's package.

[image]

However, the project builds correctly, installs and runs on a physical device without issues, *even after modifications to the source code*.

The `File -> Settings -> ... Android SDK` is in place:

[image]

Tried

- `Clean Project`
- `Rebuild Project`
- Closed and re-opened the project
- Closed and re-started Android Studio

Surely, some setting I am unable to figure out has gone haywire. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following works for me in such situations:
Go to

> "File" -> "Invalidate Caches..." and select "Invalidate and Restart"

.
Hope that helps.